# Replace NA values in column with value in row above +1

Tags: r, for-loop, na, zoo

I have the following data frame:

```
game <- c('game1','game1','game2','game2','game2','game3','game4', 'game4')
shot_number <- c(1,NA,1,NA,NA,1,1,NA)
df <- data.frame(game, shot_number)

      game     shot_number
      game1              1
      game1             NA
      game2              1
      game2             NA
      game2             NA
      game3              1
      game4              1
      game4             NA
```

I want to fill the NAs by adding 1 to the value in the row above, so the df reads as follows:

```
      game     shot_number
      game1              1
      game1              2
      game2              1
      game2              2
      game2              3
      game3              1
      game4              1
      game4              2
```

I don't know if there's some way to do this using the 'zoo' library and na.locf or if I would need to write a for loop or some kind of function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using dplyr group and cumsum:

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(game) %>% 
  mutate(shot_number_new = cumsum(is.na(shot_number)) + 1)

# Source: local data frame [8 x 3]
# Groups: game [4]
# 
#     game shot_number shot_number_new
#   <fctr>       <dbl>           <dbl>
# 1  game1           1               1
# 2  game1          NA               2
# 3  game2           1               1
# 4  game2          NA               2
# 5  game2          NA               3
# 6  game3           1               1
# 7  game4           1               1
# 8  game4          NA               2
```

Comment: This logic is cleaner than mine and will be more efficient. The base R translation, using `ave` is `ave(df$shot_number, df$game, FUN=function(i) cumsum(is.na(i)) + 1))`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a base R method that works for your example.

```
df$shot_number <- ave(df$shot_number, df$game,
                      FUN=function(i) pmin(tail(cumsum(c(1, is.na(i))), -1), i, na.rm=TRUE))
```

Here, `ave` runs the function by group (`df$game`). For each game, calculate the cumulative sum of NAs, prepending 1 to get started. Drop the final value with `tail`, as the result will be 1 element to long. Then take the minimum of this to the actual vector, removing any NAs.

This returns

```
df
   game shot_number
1 game1           1
2 game1           2
3 game2           1
4 game2           2
5 game2           3
6 game3           1
7 game4           1
8 game4           2
```

**data**

```
df <-
structure(list(game = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("game1", "game2", "game3", "game4"), class = "factor"), 
    shot_number = c(1, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA)), .Names = c("game", 
"shot_number"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

The solutions below all handle the example data in the question but assume increasingly complex general cases.  (4) is the most general but others may be preferred on grounds of simplicity if the actual situation does not require full generality.  No packages are used.

**1)** In the example data the base row within each group is 1 and the remaining numbers are NA so if that is the general pattern then we can use `ave` with `seq_along` like this.

```
transform(df, shot_number = ave(shot_number, game, FUN = seq_along))
```

**2)** If the base number were not necessarily 1 then replace `seq_along` in (1) with `f` as shown:

```
f <- function(x) seq(x[1], length = length(x))
transform(df, shot_number = ave(shot_number, game, FUN = f))
```

**2a)** This would also work under the same assumptions as (2).  It replaces each NA with 1 and then uses `cumsum` within `game` group:

```
NAtoN <- function(x, N) replace(x, is.na(x), N)
transform(df, shot_number = ave(NAtoN(shot_number, 1), game, FUN = cumsum))
```

**3)** If the general case were that there is any mixture of numbers and NAs but the first element of each game group is known not to be NA then we can form groups from the non-NAs together with the NAs that follow them:

```
transform(df, shot_number = ave(shot_number, cumsum(!is.na(shot_number)), FUN = f))
```

**4)** If the first element of a game group can be NA too then process subgroups defined by a non-NA followed by NAs or all NAs if the game group starts with NA.  Use 0 as the base value in the case of leading NAs (or replace 0 in `f2` with some other number.)

```
 f2 <- function(x) ave(NAtoN(x, 0), cumsum(!is.na(x)), FUN = f)
 transform(df, shot_number = ave(shot_number, game, FUN = f2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `group_by()` and `row_number()` without explicitly using the original `shot_number` column:

```
df %>%
  group_by(game) %>%
  mutate(shot_number2 = row_number())
```